# CSS: How to remove pseudo elements (after, before,...)?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css, pseudo-element

I would like to use a switch for the layout of paragraph tags on a webpage.

I use the after pseudoelement:

```
p:after {content: url("../img/paragraph.gif");}
```

Now I need to remove this CSS code from the page.

How can this be done easily?

I want to add that:

- jQuery is already used on the page
- and I do not want to include or remove files containing CSS.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Manipulating CSS pseudo-elements using jQuery (e.g. :before and :after)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5041494/manipulating-css-pseudo-elements-using-jquery-e-g-before-and-after)

Answer (score 620, accepted):

```
p:after {
   content: none;
}
```

*none* is the official value to set the content, if specified, to nothing.

http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_gen_content.asp

Comment: Does this actually clear out other content-related styles, thus even if you have paddings and margins set they become inert?

Comment: This should be the accepted answer. Using content: ''; could lead to unexpected results when trying to override a previously set content attribute.

Comment: Can't you just do `display: none`?

Comment: @MDTech.us_MAN yes you can do "display:none", but it will still be retained in the DOM tree. Setting content:none doesn't even put it in the DOM tree (you can check it via Chrome's DOM inspector)

Answer (score 38):

You need to add a css rule that removes the after content (*through a class*)..

---

*An **update** due to some valid comments.*

The more correct way to completely remove/disable the `:after` rule is to use

```
p.no-after:after{content:none;}
```

as [Gillian Lo Wong answered](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18736074/128165).

---

*Original answer*

You need to add a css rule that removes the after content (*through a class*)..

```
p.no-after:after{content:"";}
```

and add that class to your `p` when you want to with this line

```
$('p').addClass('no-after'); // replace the p selector with what you need...
```

a working example at : http://www.jsfiddle.net/G2czw/

Answer (score 22):

As [mentioned in Gillian's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18736074/1218980), assigning `none` to `content` solves the problem:

```
p::after {
   content: none;
}
```

Note that in *CSS3*, *W3C* recommended to use two colons (`::`) for *pseudo-elements* like `::before` or `::after`.

From the [MDN web doc on Pseudo-elements](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Pseudo-elements#Syntax):

> **Note:** As a rule, double colons (`::`) should be used instead of a single
> colon (`:`). This distinguishes pseudo-classes from pseudo-elements.
> However, since this distinction was not present in older versions of
> the W3C spec, most browsers support both syntaxes for the sake of
> compatibility. Note that `::selection` must always start with double
> colons (`::`).

Answer (score 16):

```
$('p:after').css('display','none');
```

Answer (score 7):

```css
*::after {
   content: none !important;
}
*::before {
   content: none !important;
}
```

Answer (score 6):

This depends on what's actually being added by the pseudoselectors. In your situation, setting content to `""` will get rid of it, but if you're setting borders or backgrounds or whatever, you need to zero those out specifically. As far as I know, there's no one cure-all for removing everything about a before/after element regardless of what it is.

Answer (score 1):

had a same problem few minutes ago and just `content:none;` did not do work but adding `content:none !important;` and `display:none !important;` worked for me

Answer (score 1):

There are two ways:

```
.content::after {
        visibility: hidden;
        // Or 
        content: none;
    }
```

Answer (score -4):

```
p:after {
  content: none;
}
```

This is a way to remove the `:after` and you can do the same for `:before`

Comment: This answer seems to reiterate the same solution as the currently accepted one from several years ago.  If you feel you have something to add, please leave it as a comment on the original answer.  Alternatively if you have a different solution, please explain why it's different (and possibly better).