# How to remove bootstrap padding in Chrome

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap-3

I'm trying to centre a div in a page, horizontally & vertically. This is acheived, but there is some left and right padding, in chrome. How to remove this. Works fine in firefox.

**MyStyle.css :**

```
html, body
{
  height:100%;
  margin:0;
  padding:0;
}

.container-fluid{
  height:100%;
  display:table;
  width: 100%;
  padding:0;  
}

.row-fluid 
{
  height: 100%; 
  display:table-cell; 
  vertical-align: middle;  
}

.centering {
  float:none;
  margin:0 auto;
}

// bootstrap css for .container-fluid
{
  padding-right: 15px;
  padding-left: 15px;
  margin-right: auto;
  margin-left: auto;
}
```

**HTML :**

```
<div class="container-fluid">
        <div class="row-fluid" style="background-color: blue">
            <div class="centering text-center col-lg-1" 
                 style="background-color: green">
                Yeah I'm centered
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

The blue color does not fill up the page in chrome, there is padding to the right & left.

Comment: a couple revisions but I got it working finally...see below

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok I figured it out.  There is a pseudo-element called content being added in the CSS which is causing this issue.  With the help of [css: how to remove pseudo elements (after, before, ...)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3012716/css-howto-remove-pseudo-elements-after-before) I found a solution, add this to your CSS:

```
.container-fluid:before{
    content:none;
}

.container-fluid:after{
     content:none;
}
```

And change your centering class:

```
.centering {
  float:none;
  margin:0 auto;
  padding-left:0px;
  padding-right:0px;
}
```

**[Bootply Demo](http://www.bootply.com/oCeZ1so9rA)**

Comment: that removes the padding in the green block. The color blue has to fill the page but there is padding to the page's right n left. Add 6px left n right padding to body{}. Thats how it looks right now

Comment: That worked. But I also had to add a similar 'before' class to remove padding on left side as well. Thank you so much.

Comment: Yeah I realized that after the fact and updated my answer...I like answering these types of questions b/c I learn a lot, I need to improve my CSS knowledge