# How to remove a hover effect of ::after of anchor?

Tags: css

How to remove a hover effect of ::after of anchor, without resetting the hover?
I have tried to use this but it's doesn't work.

```
a::after{
    pointer-events: none;
    cursor: default;
}
```

Comment: what hover effect?

Comment: do you check this? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3012716/css-how-to-remove-pseudo-elements-after-before

Comment: Eugine, I just want to remove the hover not the content