# Remove "::before" — CSS

Tags: html, css, blogger

[image]
Currently heading of my blogpost on blogger looks like this. So I wanted to remove this "-" like looking element from my blog, which is a `::before`. I tried this advice [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3012716/css-how-to-remove-pseudo-elements-after-before) and used a little ingenuity to added a CSS like so:

```css
div.post-body-container::before{
    content: none;
}
```

And some other variations of the same. Where am I going wrong here? 
[This is my blog](https://webapps-software.blogspot.com/2022/01/how-torrents-work.html) btw if it is needed on which I'm using Soho Neon theme.

Comment: Try content: "";

Comment: Or try with `display: none`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using a least specified selector.

In your CSS, the selector used to add the "-" is `body.item-view .post-body-container::before`, so with only `div.post-body-container::before` you will not be able to modify the rule.

You must use a more specific selector or remove it with a different rule (aka `display: none`).

PS: the same selector placed after will do it

```css
body.item-view .post-body-container::before {
    content: none;
}

/* or */

.post-body-container::before {
    display: none;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Try using `content: ''` instead.

```
div.post-body-container::before {
  content: '';
}
```